# android cursor loader with large database

Tags: android, android-cursorloader, android-anr-dialog, large-data

I am developing a contacts application and i need to support large number of contacts. lets just say that user have 1 lakh contacts.

requirements are
1)sectioned listview with fast scroll
2)search contacts as the user type with firstname or lastname , email or phonenumber

i wrote a content provider in this i have a table with 5 columns.

```
_id firstname lastname email phonenumber
```

i am using loadermanger callback with cursor loader from support library  to query the content provider.

but im facin this problems with 50000 rows in the table.

1)ANR -with this log-maybe because of constant allocating and deallocating of heap memory by cursor

```
05-30 18:59:20.775: E/CursorWindow(13798): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 54,     freeSpace() = 32, numRows = 8509
05-30 18:59:20.775: E/CursorWindow(13798): not growing since there are already 8509 row(s), max size 1048576
05-30 18:59:20.775: E/CursorWindow(13798): The row failed, so back out the new row accounting from allocRowSlot 8508
05-30 18:59:20.775: E/Cursor(13798): Failed allocating fieldDir at startPos 10537 row 8508
```

2)Removing sections code from the adapter seems to be reduced the ANR frequency but still FASTSCROLL causes ANR.

3)searching: its very slow as hell i can speed up searching using 'FTS3' but its not my requirement. i need to use 'LIKE' or 'CONTAINS' only in my query.

is this impossible to achieve this requirement? how the hell google guys are doing it?

Comment: Do you know whether it is the DB or the Binder IPC that is slow?  I think that's where I'd start.  If it is the IPC, you're going to have to check for Binder mem and thread conflicts and do a close read of AbstractWindowedCursor.  If it is SQLite, there are a number of good guides out there for query optimization.

Comment: it is the DB query which is slow. since im using cursor adapter it needs to return all the 50000 rows in the cursor. it is taking almost 7 sec.then i need iterate through  the first letters in 'firstname' column to create sections. it is making it more slow.

Comment: mmm... If you are positive that it is just the query that is slow, you are going to have to look to SQLite tricks to improve things (you've gotten me interested in testing this: I believe I've seen much better performance).  Why, for instance, do you need 50k rows?  You certainly can't show all of them on the screen, at once.  ... or send them all to the network at once.  Can you do some kind of paging?

Comment: i just want my application just like default contacts app. paging isnt an option bcz if the user wants to see the last contact then it will take long time to reach there. and i need fast scroll with sections so paging is not a good idea. is there any other way to achieve this? -thanks